# 240V Wireless 433Mhz Relay Wiring

Tags: power-supply, current, switches, relay

I have bought 220V Wireless 433Mhz Relay  (**AK-RK01S-220-A AC 220V**)

[image: 1 Picture]
[image: 2 Picture]

I'm newbie in electronics and don't know how to wire it. I think L is line and N is Neutral. That I can find in electrical socket, but
1.What is in the middle 220V then? 
2.And How should I wire my, like example, Lamp  on the right side with **ON**, **NC** and **COM** correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the circuit board in your photographs:

**NC** - Normally connected. This be continuous with *COM* when the relay is not activated

**ON** - What it says, on. This should be continuous with **COM** when the relay is activated

**N** - Neutral leg from the mains voltage

**220 V** - This is marking an unused terminal on this device, but indicates that the line voltage expected is 220 VAC.

**L** - Line power, or the hot from the mains.

If you can find a spec. sheet on this device it'd be much simpler to figure out how it is supposed to work.

The electronics on this device obviously need low voltage DC power. Given the absence of a transformer of any kind, DC power supply is probably supplied to the circuit by a combination of capacitive & resistive current limiting from the 220 VAC line. This feeds a rectifier (possibly half wave), a capacitor, and probably a cheap regulator somewhere.

The resistor on the corner and the large brown capacitor beside it are probably fed from the **220 V** terminal and make up the current limiting circuit.

Comment: No - L and N are, as the OP says, almost certainly Line and Neutral for a 220 V input.  The OP will have to examine the board, and test with an ohmmeter to see if the center terminal is connected to anything.  The ON terminal is more often marked NO for Normally Open (NC is Normally Closed). The supplier's specs (such as they are) says the thing operates from 220 Volts.

Comment: @PeterBennett I agree testing with a multimeter is the best course. Did you find an actual spec sheet anywhere? After consideration of your comment I also think that "ON" is a typo on the board for "NO" meaning normally open. If the OP does not have 220 VAC available, I think feeding the DC power section directly is a viable option. If 220 VAC is available, we can probably just forget about the center terminal entirely.

Comment: I found an ad for the device on Aliexpress, but no real datasheet.

Comment: No unfortunately I can not find data sheet,I think because that this module is from China. I Can give you direct link to it if it will help.. [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-Practical-AK-RK01S-220-A-AC-220V-1CH-433MHz-Wireless-Remote-Control-Switch-E/32567579396.html) .
Ohmeter says that 220v output is  connected with nothing.Only NC and COM giving a signal. The problem is that I can not really switch on or off relay now, because I need to program it first  with  433mhz sender on linux.And it will take a while and it would be hard to do if i would not wire it corectly.

Comment: Then @PeterBennett is correct. The terminal marked with **220 V** is no connection. The manufacturer just used a 3 terminal block because there is no cost advantage from sourcing a 2 terminal block. Apply 220 VAC to **L** and connect **N** to the neutral. Do you have 220 VAC in your area?

Comment: Yes, I can get 220V AC from my power outlet. I found already  Line and Neutral. When I wire L to Line and N to Neutral, red led diod is on. That's why i think its correct, but what about other side(ON,NC,COM)?

Comment: Wire the hot of your lamp into **ON** and the hot from the mains into **COM**. Leave the **NC** unused. The lamp's neutral and ground wires should stay connected to the mains circuits as normal for safety.

Comment: :Hot from the main" you mean **Line** from power outlet?

Answer (score 1):

So, i can answer my question self. Maybe it will be ussfull for future Problems.

L - Line
N - Neutral

COM - Line from main too

Wenn Relay gets Power from main on L and N, then ON output gets line signal, after switching Relay, NC gets line signal.

[image: Exmplanation]